# $x^{6}+30x^{5}-15x^{3}+6x-120$can't be written as products of two polynomials of rational coefficients and positive degrees.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Prove that $x^{6}+30x^{5}-15x^{3}+6x-120$ can't be written as a product of two polynomials of rational coefficients and positive degrees.

Comment: Eisenstein polynomial.

Comment: In that case we say the polynomial is **irreducible** over the complex numbers.  That will give you something to look up.

Comment: @GEdgar over the complex numbers?

Comment: Look at $p=3$ and use Eisenstein.

Comment: The question says rational coefficients.  If the OP does not use the word "irreducible" then he/she likely does not know what "Eisenstein" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) = x^{6}+30x^{5}-15x^{3}+6x-120$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.
Then it is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by [Gauss's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_%28ring_theory%29).
However it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) using the prime number $3$. This is a contradiction. Hence $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$